# xls file read , write in mobile application and sync operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, synchronization, offline

i am currently trying to implement a xls file read write operation in an iOS application.

So basically the requirement is, there is a big xls file which is having many dropdown , data or empty space present in a particular server.So very first time when multiple users open the app , they have to download that xls file & based on xls file a form will be created on app & later user can perform read & write operation on that form(although network is not available). But Once network is available , all the users can sync it back to the server.

Now i have 2 options

**Option 1:**

Create a CSV file from xls sheet on server side & send it to user.So user will perform Read & Write operation and save all data in sqlite db & on network availability they sync it back to server.

**Option 2:**

Create a webservice which will be created by using that xls file & send the XML to device, so based on XML user will create form and do offline mode read write operation & on network availability app will create a new XML file and sync it back to server.

So between option 1 and 2 which one is better & why ?

Any webservice is available to do such operation ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of data you are getting, how many columns your csv file has, if the no. of columns are less i.e 2-5, 1st option would be better.
But if you have data with many columns, you must use XML, and XML is very good for storing hierarchical data.